# Using two argument values for an option with getopt

Tags: bash, getopt

Have been using `getopt` for some time.  I am looking into the possibility of having two argument values for an option.  Is this good and possible to do this with `getopt`.  An example would help.

Have done some tests and figured out that doing

```
myfunc -S 13 21
```

gives

```
opts:  -S '13' -- '21'
```

where

```
opts=$( getopt -o "$shortopts" -l "$longopts" -n "${0##*/}" -- "$@" )
```

Thusly getopt is incapable of accepting `myfunc -S 13 21`.

Comment: An example for what you want to achieve would help too .....

Answer (score 1):

I am handling things this way

```
 while (( $# > 0 )); do
   case $1 in
    ("-S"|"--seam")
      [[ "$2" = +([[:digit:]]) ]] && { sp="$2" ; shift ; }
      [[ "$2" = +([[:digit:]]) ]] && { sq="$2" ; shift ; }
      ;;
   esac
 done
```